# How do i loop through my vectors fleetX and fleetY and access the functions in my "Ship" base class?

Tags: c++, class, vector, shared-ptr

I want to create two fleets with maximum 9 ships and have them fight each other. I was told by my teacher i have to use shared pointers and vectors.

- Base class: Ship
- Inherited classes: Destroyer, Cruiser, Hunter

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ship>> fleetX;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ship>> fleetY;

Battlefield game;

game.createFleet(fleetX, fleetY);

return 0;
```

}

createFleet() in my Battlefield class

```
void Battlefield::createFleet(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ship>> fleetX, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ship>> fleetY) {

int hunter, destroyer, cruiser, player_Input;

// PLAYER 1
do {
    cout << "BATTLEFIELD" << endl;
    cout << "Player_1" << endl;
    cout << "Choose the number of ships you want in your fleet (9 maximum): ";
    cin >> player_Input;
} while (player_Input < 1 || player_Input > 9);
cout << endl;

do  {
    cout << "Choose " << player_Input << " in total ships from the following:" << endl;
    cout << "HUNTER - Special Attack (Critical Hit)" << endl;
    cout << "DESTROYER - Special Attack (Target Search)" << endl;
    cout << "CRUISER - Special Attack (Bombardment)" << endl << endl;
    cout << "HUNTER: ";
    cin >> hunter;
    cout << "DESTROYER: ";
    cin >> destroyer;
    cout << "CRUISER: ";
    cin >> cruiser;
    cout << endl;
} while (hunter + destroyer + cruiser != player_Input);

int iterator = 0;
while (iterator < hunter) { fleetX.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Ship>(new Hunter())); iterator++;} iterator = 0;
while (iterator < destroyer) { fleetX.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Ship>(new Destroyer())); iterator++;} iterator = 0;
while (iterator < cruiser) { fleetX.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Ship>(new Cruiser())); iterator++;} iterator = 0;

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the vector by value causing a new copy to be created i.e. not modifying the original vector.

Try passing the vector by reference

```cpp
void Battlefield::createFleet(
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ship>>& fleetX, 
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ship>>& fleetY
) {
  // rest of code
}
```

Edit:

Use `std::make_shared<Hunter>()` instead of `std::shared_ptr(new Hunter())`